# How is a service mesh different from a 2010 ESB solution like IBM IIB or Oracle ESB

Tags: containers, esb, soa, istio

Back in the days, I used to be a IBM Integration Bus (IIB) - then known as IBM WebSphere Message Broker - developer. I would develop message flows to connect various input, output and processing nodes. This development style, of course, extends to other ESB vendors too; so, this question does not lose generality.

The messaging engine for IIB is WebSphere MQ (WMQ) that provides communication in the form of messages on a queue or as topics. Together with internal logic in IIB, the nodes communicate with each other passing on messages. 
A typical IIB/WMQ has well-documented HA installation mechanism too.  Besides, if a message flow exposes a HTTP(S) end-point, it could do so behind a load balancer too.

Similarly, one can speak about other technologies that comprised the SOA era. Therefore, my question is, if I

- develop micro-services that communicated with say, WMQ
- deployed each micro-service to a container
- used an ESB to orchestrate these micro-services
- relied on ESB (and its ancillary technologies) for access control, traffic management, etc.

then, what do I need Istio for - apart from a 'pure containers based architecture'?

https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2014/07/02/ibm-integration-bus-high-availability-overview/

https://developer.ibm.com/integration/docs/ibm-integration-bus/learn-play/an-introduction-to-ibm-integration-bus/

Answer (score 2):

Istio implements the side-car pattern to be coupled to each microservice. The microservices (not necessarily but usually) are deployed in infrastructures that allow elastic scaling, in which the system is delegated the task of adjusting the number of instances of each microservice based on the scaling strategy configured. This means that the number of containers at any given moment is predictable and at the same time unknown in the short term.

Istio solves the problem of abstracting microservices from purely infrastructure tasks and leaving them to focus solely on the functional plane, and at the same time it is able to elastically scale together with the containers to which it is attached.

Delegating this task to an ESB is not impossible, but in my opinion it would introduce a fairly high complexity factor. Maybe you've found a business opportunity ;-)

Answer (score 1):

IIB previously had a monolithic architecture and your IIB related links provided would help in creating a High Availability architecture. The recent offerings of ESB(any vendor) has been to deploy the ESB as a microservices. Specifically, with respect to IIB, we can run each execution group(Integration server) as a container. With this you have all kinds of advantages of a microservice architecture. Of course as mentioned, you can have these ESB microservice to do orchestration as well.

But for any Enterprise that has microservices based architecture across its various applications and not just ESB as containers, its very difficult to manage, secure, observe etc. Specially  when microservices keep growing with thousands of it running in an enterprise. This is where Istio would help.

https://istio.io/docs/concepts/what-is-istio/

Comment: With IIB execution groups as containers, who does the orchestration? IIB itself?

Comment: Yes, IIB would continue to do what it does, just the way it runs changes instead of one large monolith it now runs as microservice. Below is a link fore more details : https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2018/01/12/iib-mq-micro-services-builder-ibm-cloud-private/

Answer (score 1):

The TLDR answer is that istio is more flexible and not trying to get the microservices fully dependent on istio, while the IIB stack was mostly "once you go in, you can't go out without a migration project".